# PHP GET number query

Tags: php

**Hi to all!**
I have a query that gets the name and an id.
The results is like this **:**
54 - Rian Ree Barrientos
I wanted to get the number **54**.
I used **echo (int)$_GET['number'];**
But the result is "**0**". How can I get the number?

Comment: Is the query you have a MySql query, a URI query string, or something else?  Once you tell us that, we can get you the corrrect answer pretty quickly.  Otherwise, we are answering somewhat blindly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get it that way, you need to make two query string vars for it eg:

```
<a href="somepage.php?number=54&str=some_string">
```

Make sure that if you do so, you use the `urlencode` function.

Now you can use:

```
echo (int) $_GET['number'];
```

And:

```
echo $_GET['str'];
```

Otherise you can use the `explode` function to get the two values by specifying the `-` delimiter.

Comment: why `mysql_real_escape_string`? oO

Comment: @knittl: Yup, not needed really.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want id from the value you get from the query

I think you want something like following

```
$strPrice1 = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM table_name where id=".$_GET['id'] );
$strPrice = mysql_fetch_array($strPrice1); 
echo (int)$_strPrice['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

> But the result is "0". How can I get the number?

Really?

When I run:

```
print (int)('54 - Rian Ree Barrientos') . "\n";
```

I get 54

(php v 5.1.6)

Maybe $_GET['number'] doesn't contain what you think.

C.